# Which boost library to link to?

Tags: c++, boost

Okay so I've got a very small program containing these three boost imports:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

But that's just an example I'd like an answer that's applicable to other headers as well if possible. Now taking a look into /usr/lib results in a list of 39 static library objects I could possible link to (or rather put into my CMakeLists.txt):
[List of libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcSk2.png)

How can I know which library is implementing which boost header in /usr/include/boost?

This is the relevant part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost
    1.63.0
    REQUIRED
    ????
)
```

Comment: Generally, each top-level Boost header file (like the ones you include) corresponds to a single Boost "library". So in your case the libraries you are using are `asio`, `lexical_cast` and `thread`. Note that many Boost libraries are *header-only* and don't have any corresponding link-library.

Comment: So for asio and lexical_cast I'd just include the headers and additionally link to libboost_thread.a for the last one right? Okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost libraries has a naming convention defined in the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming). E.g. `libboost_thread.a` is a static library for `Boost.Thread`.

In the header source you can find related library name, e.g. in `boost/thread.hpp` there is:

```
//  See www.boost.org/libs/thread for documentation.
```

Next you need to understand library is header-only or not. Check the list [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries).

Some libraries requires the other Boost libraries, e.g. [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html) requires `Boost.System` and `Boost.Regex` in some cases. Check library usage [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/libraries.html) to understand such dependencies.